# Is option type in F# reference type?

Tags: .net, f#

Is uint64 option type reference type or value type? I am having some performance issues related to this. please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

As `None` is implicitly represented as `null`, `Option` is a reference type.

The F# spec gives the following definition which requires option to be a reference type:

```
[<DefaultAugmentation(false)>]
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue)>]    
type 'T option =
    | None 
    | Some of 'T
    static member None : 'T option
    static member Some : 'T -> 'T option
    [<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.Instance)>]
    member Value : 'T
    member IsSome : bool
    member IsNone : bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Option<'T> = 
        | None :       'T option
        | Some : Value:'T -> 'T option
```

from [FSharp Source Code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs) shows that is a reference type.